# Bootstrap modal fit width and center horizontally

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have seen solutions for limiting a modal's width to a certain percent of the page or to a certain column span, but is it possible to simply get the modal to best fit - that is use the minimal width of the modal content?

I tried to add `width: auto;` without success.

See:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" style="width:auto">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:auto">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <img src="http://pdf.buildasign.com/upload/images/templateImages/TC17819031-42-260-195-7357-11-SharedDesign.png">
      <br>
      <p>hello</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vyw2zvfu/)

I would like the modal width to be that of the top banner (plus some margin), the modal to be centered and the width/centering to maintain itself if the page width changes.

Thanks!

Comment: did you try adding the width auto to modal-content as well?

Comment: You won't be able to do this using just CSS; the modal needs a defined width for the left and right margins to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a comprehensive solution, saving the original width and using it to calculate width and left-margin percent on shown event and doc resize. Hiding the dialog initially to prevent the flicker effect.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content" style="display:none;">
        <img src="http://pdf.buildasign.com/upload/images/templateImages/TC17819031-42-260-195-7357-11-SharedDesign.png">
        <br>
        <p>hello</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
function hCenterModals() {
    function toP(n) { return (n * 100).toFixed() + '%'; }

    $('.modal').each(function () {
        var modalDialog = $(this).find('.modal-dialog'),
            modalContent = $(this).find('.modal-content');

        // get/save minWidth to data (for resize)
        var minWidth = modalDialog.data('minWidth');
        if (!minWidth) {
            minWidth = modalContent.width();
            if (minWidth > 0) {
                modalDialog.data('minWidth', minWidth);
                console.log('saved ' + minWidth);
            } else {
                minWidth = 0;
            }
        }

        if (minWidth>0 && modalDialog.is(':visible')) {
            var widthFrac = minWidth / $(window).width();

            modalDialog.css({
                'width': toP(widthFrac),
                'margin-left': toP((1 - widthFrac) / 2)
            });
        }
    });
}

$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    hCenterModals();
    var modalContent = $(this).find('.modal-content');
    modalContent.show();
});

$(window).resize(hCenterModals).trigger("resize");
```

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vyw2zvfu/6/)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to handle the `shown.bs.modal` event, and resize the div to whatever, like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/vyw2zvfu/2/

```
$(function(){

    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e){

        var width = $(this).find('.modal-content img').width();

        $(this).animate({ 'width': width+25 });

    });

});
```

You'll notice that the modal starts at it's default size, however.

Comment: nice solution but `$(this).css({ 'width': width+25 });` , is slightly better then `$(this).animate({ 'width': width+25 });` .. but yes , the default width is still seen when the modal loads .

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Define "slightly better"? The end result is the same, if you inspect the modal's markup in, say, Firebug.

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik I am aware of that. I purposely chose to animate the width. You are free to add an answer sans animation, if you like.

Comment: this kind of work but I just need the modal to appear in the middle, no animation and no skipping from wide to narrow ...